# Trouble using a For Next variable in "xxxx.Rows.Count"

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

In the code block below I am wishing to use a variable in a xxxx.Rows.Count line.
Specifically, I'm wanting to take the "R1200s" portion and increment it to R1201s, R1202s, R1203s and so on as the For-Next loop executes. I, of course, already have the DataTable()'s portion defined... no problem there. The code works fine if I write out every single instance but I'd like to shorten up into a simpler block of code. I've been able to use "i" in every other control with success but getting hung up on only this portion.
I've tried something like ("R120" & i & "s"), along with many variations of this but, can find no solution that works.
Any help, or a point in the right direction, is appreciated.

```
For i = 1 To 8
    Dim Ai As Label = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("A" & ID.ToString()), Label)
    Dim Si As Hyperlink = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("S" & ID.ToString()), Hyperlink)

    If R1200s.Rows.Count < Slots.Rows(0)(Ri).ToString() +1 Then

       Ai.Style.Add("background-color","#000000")
       Si.ImageUrl = "images/" & ID & ".png"
       Si.NavigateUrl = "step3.aspx?Time=" & ID & "&Date=" & Request.QueryString("Date") & "&Day=" & Request.QueryString("Day") & "&Entry=" & Request.QueryString("Entry")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: list the Datatable names in an array, and `Set` the object reference inside the loop to whichever datatable the loop index is at, then use that object reference for your `.rows.count` statement?

Comment: I'm getting an error returned saying "'Let' and 'Set' assignment statements are no longer supported." Could I implore you to provide a sample block of code as a starting point? I can hopefully take it from there. Appreciated.